# ObjectiveC allocation and init?

Tags: objective-c

I have just made a sample short demo program for fun when I was playing with Objective-C:

Some piece of code:

```
// TestClass.h:    
@interface TestClass : NSObject {
        int someNumber;
        float someFloat;

    }
    @property int someNumber;
    @property float someFloat;

    // Returns String containing some instance values:
    -(NSString *)getNiceString;
    // Returns always the same string:
    -(NSString *)getAnotherString;
    -(id)init;

    @end
```

--

```
//TestClass.m:
#import "TestClass.h"

@implementation TestClass

@synthesize someFloat;
@synthesize someNumber;

-(NSString*) getNiceString{

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:
            @"Float number: %f and the number is: %d", self.someFloat, self.someNumber];
}

-(NSString *) getAnotherString{
    return [NSString stringWithString:@"TEST STRING"];
} 

-(id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        self.someFloat = 100.34;
        self.someNumber = 324;

        return self;
    }
    return nil;
}
@end
```

And some main stuff:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "TestClass.h"


int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        TestClass* instance = [TestClass alloc];
        // Version 2: 
        // TestClass* instance = [[TestClass alloc]init];

        NSLog(@"%@", [instance getNiceString]);
        NSLog(@"%@", [instance getAnotherString]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I use `TestClass* instance = [TestClass alloc];` in main the output is:

> 2013-03-05 09:56:34.767 ObjectiveTest[8367:903] Float number: 0.000000
>   and the number is: 0 2013-03-05 09:56:34.770 ObjectiveTest[8367:903]
>   TEST STRING

When the second version is used instead (`TestClass* instance = [[TestClass alloc]init];`):

> 2013-03-05 10:06:46.743 ObjectiveTest[8421:903] Float number:
>   100.339996 and the number is: 324 2013-03-05 10:06:46.750 ObjectiveTest[8421:903] TEST STRING

The question is **if `[TestClass alloc]` makes any initialization stuff** (String is returned properly and values are zeros)... It is worth to mention that if I remove the `-(id)init:` implementation from TestClass.m the outputs for versions with `init` and without it are exactly the same... Is there any default initialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The question is if [TestClass alloc] makes any initialization stuff (String is returned properly and values are zeros)... It is worth to mention that if I remove the -(id)init: implementation from TestClass.m the outputs for versions with init and without it are exactly the same... Is there any default initialization?

alloc doesn't initialize any member, so if you just call alloc, then someFloat will not be initialized (default value will be 0.0). If you keep away your alloc method from your class implementation the same happens: someFloat will not be initialized and it will have a default value of 0.0 .

But calling just alloc and not init has many disadvantages: all the subclass initializers will not be called, thus you will not be able to use some NSObject's attributes, you shouldn't call just alloc. alloc-init is always used by convention.

Comment: Thank's for that answer ; )

Answer (score 2):

alloc will zero out the memory region. More detail can be found here [What happens when alloc or allocWithZone is called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8846646/what-happens-when-alloc-or-allocwithzone-is-called)

Answer (score 1):

`alloc` doesn't initialize the object correctly, and so must always be used.

The float isn't initialized correctly (`0.000 != 100.34`) and the string is the result of calling a method which returns a string literal, not an instance variable.